# How to make localhost public with XAMPP

Tags: networking, xampp, webserver, hosting

I have recently purchased a VPS from AWS (using Windows Server 2016). I installed XAMPP and got a localhost server running but I would like to know how to access the site from an external IP.
(Example: Let's say my IP is 0.0.0.0, how could I make it so that other users outside of my network can type 0.0.0.0 into their browser and access the website?)

Answer (score 0):

This is called "port forwarding my ip"  you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here , and how to access my localhost in WAN , it will only take u couple of minutes before u reach ur goal , goodluck !

This video May help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBcXdZXBhic

Also this depends on your router too so make sure to google ur model too :)